# Задание из учебника Python на PHP

Tags: php, php7

Есть задание в учебнике по Python:

> Создайте список или кортеж, содержащий серию из 10 чисел и 5 букв. Случайным образом выберите 4 числа или буквы из списка. Выведите сообщение о том, что билет, содержащий эту комбинацию из четырех цифр или букв, является выигрышным.
> Анализ лотереи: напишите цикл, который проверяет, насколько сложно выиграть в смоделированной вами лотерее. Создайте список или кортеж с именем my_ticket. Напишите цикл, который продолжает генерировать комбинации до тех пор, пока не выпадет выигрышная комбинация. Выведите сообщение с информацией о том, сколько выполнений цикла понадобилось для получения выигрышной комбинации.

В общем смысл сделать массив из которого берётся 4 значения и сравниваются с переменной из 4х символов. Значения перебираются до тех пор пока не совпадут, кол-во итераций записывается.
Я решил попробовать сделать это на php, однако получилась ересь, поправьте меня пожалуйста, что сделал не так и скажите как бы это сделать проще и правильнее.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,'a','b','c','d');

$answer = array_rand( $arr , 4 );

$numb1 = $arr[$answer[0]];
$numb2 = $arr[$answer[1]];
$numb3 = $arr[$answer[2]];
$numb4 = $arr[$answer[3]];

$numb = $numb1 . $numb2 . $numb3 . $numb4 ;

$final = "12cd";

for ($s=0; $numb != $final ; $s++) { 
    
    if ($numb == $final){
        echo $s;
        exit;
    }

};

?>
```

*Почти уверен, что я написал ужасно, но ничего другого не придумал, к сожалению.*

Comment: пока что у вас текущая комбинация $numb составляется единожды. вам нужна функция типа `$numb = function(){ $arr = [...]; return implode('', array_rand(...)); }` надо ее в цикле `while(++$s){....}` получать, и если уж вдруг совпало, то сделать break

Comment: @teran а можете мне пояснить, почему у меня при выводе, если попадается буква, то её выводит в виде числа, а не символа. Как это исправить? где то я накосячил опять.
`$numb = function(){
    $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,'a','b','c','d');
    return implode('', array_rand($arr , 4));
    };

echo ($numb());`

Comment: потому что `array_rand` возвращает случайные индексы массива, а не значения. косячный код у меня был

Comment: @teran а как сделать возвращение именно того, что нужно, я просто как кодер вообще не алё, но гугЕл мне понятного не дал. просто если он выдаёт индексы, я должен выковыривать каждое число по индексу и склеивать заного? но если у меня чисел будет 100 например... это же не серьёзно получается, может есть способ попроще?

Comment: короче всего сделать `shuffle($arr); return implode('', array_slice($arr, 0,4));`

Answer (score 0):

По итогу это, не совсем то, что нужно, но оно выполняет ту же функцию, только не берётся 4 случайных символа из массива, а перемешивается сам массив и берётся 4 числа.

```
$numb = function(){
    $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,'a','b','c','d');
    shuffle($arr); 
    return implode('', array_slice($arr, 0,4));
};

$cc = "4568";

$count = 0;

while ($numb() !== $cc) {
    
    $numb();
    $count++;

};

echo "<br>";
echo("количество попыток для получения числа $cc, равно $count");
```